# Writing jobname and day to auxiliary file

Tags: tex-core, auxiliary-files

I'm confused about why `\immediate\write` evaluates some commands but not others.  E.g. `\immediate\write\file{\jobname, \day}` correctly expands `\jobname` but writes "\day" as itself.  How can I write the current date to an auxiliary file?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE :-)

Answer (score 2):

It is not related to `\write` really. `\jobname` is expandable and expands to the filename, `\day` is not expandable, it is like a count register, so you want `\the\day` to get the decimal value as an expansion.

Comment: Awesome, thanks!  What threw me off was I first tried to write `\today`, and obviously you can't do `\the\today`.  I get with `\the` you can get the pieces of `\today` (and `\currenttime`) for an auxiliary file.  For my edification, though, is there a way to write `\today` or, say, `\today at \currenttime` to a file as it would appear in a document?

Comment: @NathanielChristen the default definition of `\today` is expandable so you can simply use `\today`  `\currenttime` is not a command I recognise